# pandas to_numeric couldn't convert string values to integers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I am trying to use `pandas.to_numeric` to convert a series to `int`s.

```
df['numeric_col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['numeric_col'], errors='raise')
```

I got errors,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_name/script.py", line 86, in execute
data = module(**module_args).execute(data)
  File "/home/user_name/script.py", line 62, in execute
invoices['numeric_invoice_no'] = pd.to_numeric(invoices['numeric_invoice_no'], errors='raise')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/numeric.py", line 126, in to_numeric
coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1052, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric (pandas/_libs/lib.c:56638)
ValueError: Integer out of range. at position 106759
```

if I change it to,

```
df['numeric_col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['numeric_col'], errors='coerce')
```

the values in `numeric_col` will not convert to `int`s, i.e. they are still `string`s.

if I changed to,

```
df['numeric_col'] = df['numeric_col'].astype(int)
```

I got error,

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

so I have to change it to,

```
df['numeric_col'] = df['numeric_col'].astype(float)
```

then there was no error generated.

The size of the series is about 994572, the strings in the column are like `52333612273`, `56032860` or `02031757`.

I am wondering what are the issues with `to_numeric` and `astype` here.

I am running `Python 3.5` on `Linux mint 18.1 64-bit`.

Comment: You have some value that exceeds the limits for a 64-bit integer hence the error. What do you intend to do with these values

Comment: @EdChum I intend to do some simple arithmetics, so convert to `float` works as well, but just wondering why converting `int` doesn't work.

Comment: isn't it clear that your value exceeds the numerical limits for a [64-bit int](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9,223,372,036,854,775,807)?

Comment: Check the maximum values by `np.finfo('float64').max`  and `np.iinfo('int64').max`.  Max value for integers is way smaller.

Comment: @EdChum just no clear which value, is there a way to rule out the value that exceeds the limit, or to locate the value, where is it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a comma(,) within your numeric string values or still having a null value(NaN) within the columns of your dataframe , so try to replace the commas with empty space using the
.replace() method
and then drop or fill in the Null values with
.fillna() or .replace or .dropna()

before using
df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].astype(int)

Comment: If you need more details from the OP, you can always ask them in the comments of the question